# npm:ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

i tried install vue cli.but I am getting a lot of strange errors. I searched for errors but could not find them:

```sh
linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$ sudo npm install vue -g 






[sudo] password for linux: 
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EAI_AGAIN: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/vue failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
+ vue@2.6.12
updated 1 package in 10.676s





linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$ vue --version





'vue'  komutu sistemde bulunamadı. Ama şununla kurulabilir:

sudo snap install vue




linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$ npm i -g @vue/cli





npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@vue%2fcli-ui-addon-webpack (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/linux/.npm/_logs/2020-09-24T17_37_08_787Z-debug.log






linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$ npm i -g vue-cli@2.9.6





npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/linux/.npm/_logs/2020-09-24T17_40_02_518Z-debug.log




linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$ npm cache clean 





npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/linux/.npm/_logs/2020-09-24T17_40_33_560Z-debug.log



linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$ sudo npm cache clean 



npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-24T17_40_40_872Z-debug.log





linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$ sudo npm cache clean --force





npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.





linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$
```

I searched everything on the internet, I asked questions in many forums but unfortunately I could not find an answer. Finally, I opened the topic here hoping to find an answer.
guys please help me.Thanks

Comment: The error `reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443` normally is **network related** (**DNS, firewall policy etc**).

Answer (score 1):

Vue namespaced their cli (from v3). Use `npm i -g @vue/cli`

EDIT: Check the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) for more info

Comment: oh guy thank you.i try run your command with sudo and this  work.thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$ sudo npm i -g @vue/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @vue/compiler-sfc@3.0.0 requires a peer of vue@3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/linux/.npm/_logs/2020-09-24T18_13_12_868Z-debug.log
linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$ vue --version

'vue'  komutu sistemde bulunamadı. Ama şununla kurulabilir:

sudo snap install vue

linux@admin:~/Masaüstü/learn-vue$
```

Comment: try with `sudo`

Answer (score -3):

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\moham/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\moham\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-30T09_56_30_171Z-debug.log

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).